# Rotating an int array clockwise in java

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I want to rotate an int array by 90 degrees in either clockwise or anti clockwise direction. The array is a 1D array and rotation should be done as if it is been done on a bit matrix without changing the contents of array to bits.

```
    For eg

    [B,2,4,9] --> [9,5,2,8] (For Clockwise)
              --> [1,4,A,9] (For Anti Clockwise)
```

This should be done in the most efficient way possible.
Here is the code I wrote to rotate a bit matrix in clockwise direction.

```
public void CT(int mat[][])
{
   transpose(mat);
   int t;
   for(int i=0;i<SIDE_LENGTH;i++)
   {
       t = mat[i][0];
       mat[i][0] = mat[i][SIDE_LENGTH-1];
       mat[i][SIDE_LENGTH-1] = t;
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: The only solution I can come up with till now is to convert the array into a bit matrix, rotate it and convert it back, but I don't want to convert the array as it will reduce the performance. I was hoping there might be some bit based operations which can do the rotation without the requirement to convert the array.

Comment: Is your post right and I'm stupid or do you do some magic there?

Comment: @Keppil added the code I used to rotate the bit matrix. I need the same transformation without converting the numbers to bits.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Convert the numbers in the array to bits, rotate and convert them back